# animate.css causes other elements to "bounce"

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I created some landing pages ([here's a demo](http://gan-pashosh.co.il/lp/ganp/))and used animate.css.
It works great, but other elements on the screen appears to be "bouncing" a little bit when the animation fires (see the testimonials section in the bottom of the page).

[You can use this for debugging](http://pastebin.com/1svSGvPt) (it causes the animation to run continuously so it is more visible), just copy&paste it in the browser console.

How can I fix this?

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Chrome 33 Ubuntu...

Comment: The 1st of the 3 pictures moves 2 pixels left when the animation happens, hope that helps in finding the solution.

Comment: I couldn't see anything either. The only weird thing I saw was in Opera, there wasn't any background color in the buttons.